# How to solve weird and unwanted SwiftUI Animation in transition?

Tags: swift, macos, animation, cocoa, swiftui

I am using a SwiftUI View for my content in macOS Cocoa in this code:

```
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.wantsLayer = true
        self.view = NSHostingView(rootView: ContentView())
    }

}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var myArray: [CustomType] = [CustomType(1), CustomType(2), CustomType(3), CustomType(4), CustomType(5)]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            
            ForEach(myArray, id:\.id) { item in
                
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.red)
                    .frame(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
                    .overlay(content: {
                        Text(String(describing: item.value))
                            .font(Font.system(.largeTitle, design: .monospaced))
                    })
                    .transition(AnyTransition.scale)
                
            }
            
            Button("add") {
                myArray.append(CustomType(myArray.count + 1))
            }
            
            Button("remove") {
                if (myArray.count > 0) { myArray.removeLast() }
            }
        }
        .padding(30)
        .animation(.linear(duration: 0.2), value: myArray.count)
        
    }
    
    struct CustomType: Identifiable {
        
        let id: UUID = UUID()
        var value: Int
        
        init(_ value: Int) {
            self.value = value
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

The issue that I have with the animation is an unwanted jump! The content jumps up or down in addition or removal of Circles. The transition that I am using is needed as the effect but that jump to up or down is not what I want. How to solve this jump issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you want things to animate instead of snap into place, you need to wrap the state changes in a `withAnimation` block.

It would look like this:

```swift
 
            Button("add") {
                withAnimation {
                    myArray.append(CustomType(myArray.count + 1))
                }
            }
            
            Button("remove") {
                if (myArray.count > 0) { 
                    withAnimation {
                        myArray.removeLast() 
                    }
                }
            }
```

[image: Proof it works gif]

Comment: Notice you're currently only animating on the `count` not the items in the array.